# adding cookie to angular $http requests (post and get) in an iframe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, iframe, cookies

i have an angular application that runs in an `iFrame`
the outer application is doing authentication and saving a cookie with `jsessionid`.
i need my `iFrame` application to send requests with the cookie that the outer application saved.
i'm using

`$http.post`
  `$http.get`

i have tried to include this on my service module

`$http.defaults.withCredentials = true;`

doesnt seem to work.
any help would be apreciated.

Comment: doubt you will get much help with such limited information provided.

Comment: i just want to know how to add the cookie to the requests from the `iframe`.

Comment: Are the outer application and iframe application served from the same domain?

Comment: yes, same domain of course, forgot to mention.